# What is faster; drawing a line or creating a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, drawing

I'm working with Javascript/jQuery and I'm trying to figure out what is more advantageous. I want to draw a single line which will be dynamically, according to events, changing its own height, it will have just 1px width and it will be flashing on the site. Should I create just ordinary div with width of 1px or draw a line with some javascript library function?

Comment: Well, i guess "drawing" means you'll have to use a <canvas> element, which is not available in all browser.

Comment: Thought about `<hr>` http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html ?

Comment: I thought the question was "which is faster" not "what should I do".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a native element will always be faster than implementing a custom version on your own. Elements are created by the browser's own executable code while anything you create will be done through its interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a `div` as you know it is cross browser/mobile browser compatible. If you use some sort of javascript library function, then you might find that it doesnt work in certain browsers/browser updates.

Also it gives you the advantage of styling with css which again is cross browser compatible.

Comment: We have all been there when a javascript function stops working in an IE version update :P

Answer (score 0):

HTML/CSS is definitely faster although you might not be able to achieve what you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

If u use canvas or some svg library to draw line , then it will be much cross browser compatible..

Also it will take much more processing  ...

So it would be better to use div for this purpose ...